# Schedule VBA macros on shared Excel File to run Daily?

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, onedrive

I have a VBA macro that loads data into the workbook from the database. Currently we share these workbooks with others using Sharepoint, but I want to see how to best schedule the VBA macro once a day for a handful of workbooks, so that the macro runs in each workbook and saves (refreshes) on the shared site.

Is there a way to do this? Perhaps using "office scripts", or OneDrive even?

Comment: Typically you'd use Windows Task Scheduler for this, maybe in combination with a short vbscript to run the macros.  Eg see https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/how-to-automatically-run-excel-vba-macros-daily

Comment: @TimWilliams Hey thank you so much! I since checked that link out and learned about vbscript + task scheduler.... very interesting stuff.